# Hugs `/` vs. Type Inference

Tags: haskell, hugs

In GHCi the following code works fine:

```
f1 :: Float
f1 = f2

-- f2 :: Float
f2 = 1/1
```

But in Hugs, I get a type error - it wants to be a Double. When I uncomment the type signature of f2, it works fine.

Shouldn't exactly this be taken care of the type inference?

**Is this a bug in Hugs?**

I checked out the type of `/` and the instances of `Double` and `Float` - `/` works on `Fractional`s, and there is a Fractional instance for both `Double` and `Float`, so this should not be the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When bound without type signature, `f2` has a polymorphic inferred type (`Fractional a => a`), that has to be monomorphised because of the monomorphism restriction (unless that is disabled). In the absence of other default declarations, a type variable with a `Fractional` constraint defaults to `Double`. Hugs seems to do the defaulting first, and then choke on the attempt of binding the declared `Float` `f1` to the `Double` value `f2`. GHC looks further and sees that `f2` is used at type `Float`, and hence monomorphises `f2` to `Float`.

I'm not sure what behaviour the language standard mandates in this situation, but I think GHC's is correct, because the monomorphising should only occur after typing a binding group, and I think that `f1` and `f2` together form a binding group, because `f1` uses `f2`.